# How to prevent Facebook app being used by bots

Tags: asp.net, facebook, security, captcha

I need to build a Facebook iFrame app that runs a competition where users earn points by doing various activities on the site.  The winner of the competition will be the user with the most points.
How can I prevent someone using a bot to rack up points on the site?  I dont think using a Captcha is really viable, as there are a lot of different areas of the site where user's can earn points and I dont want the user to have to do a Captcha every time they enter the site.

Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You could analyse the time between doing activities, and if it's too regular then ban the user. You could also analyse for patterns in execution, such as "Click A, wait up to 0.5 seconds, then B, then repeat".

Of course this isn't fool proof (bot could add a random time delay between operations), but if the tasks are menial enough to be performed by a bot and you don't want Captcha-style human validation, it might be sufficient. This may be only worth doing for the users with the most points.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the [Facebook Signed Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/) - it stores a unique information about every logged user. So a single scenario would be to check for the presence of Facebook context(presence of the signed request) some user ids, etc. If there is no such think you should redirect to the home page of the application.

Comment: But couldn't a bot pretend to be a legitimate Facebook user? or at least a person could run their bot after they have logged in.